# "Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string" in Craft CP

Tags: entries, error-message

After updating some fields for entry types and submitting new entries, I'm getting a `"Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string"` in the Craft control panel upon trying to access any of the entries.

I can still create entries, but once created, I cannot access it again.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

The error it's giving back to me is on line 34

`craft/app/templates/entries/_edit.html(34)`

```
22         {% if not isVersion %}
23             <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="{{ section.id }}">
24             {% if entry.id %}<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">{% endif %}
25             {% if craft.isLocalized() %}<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="{{ entry.locale }}">{% endif %}
26         {% else %}
27             <input type="hidden" name="versionId" value="{{ entry.versionId }}">
28         {% endif %}
29 
30         <div class="grid first">
31             <div class="item" data-position="left" data-min-colspan="2" data-max-colspan="3">
32                 <div id="fields" class="pane">
33                     {% include "_includes/tabs" %}
34                     {% include "entries/_fields" with {
35                         static: isVersion
36                     } %}
37                 </div>
38             </div><!--/item-->
39 
40             <div class="item" data-position="right" data-colspan="1">
41 
42                 {% if showPreviewBtn %}
43                     {% include "_includes/previewbtns" %}
44                 {% endif %}
45 
46                 {% if craft.isLocalized() and section.getLocales() | length > 1 %}
```

Comment: I'd say one of your fields in that entry is causing the error. Can you narrow it down by removing some until the error goes away?

Comment: Do you have "Restrict uploads to a single folder" set? What is "(Default) Upload Location" set to?

Comment: Doh! Yes. It had an invalid variable set in the path... That was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by an incorrectly configured assets field in the entry type. The upload location had an invalid variable set in the path.